# docker image with minikube inside

Tags: docker, minikube

Im trying to ceate a docker image with minikube installed on it.

I have tried a few steps using openjdk:8 image as the base:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
RUN echo "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y kubectl


RUN apt-get install sudo -y
ENV MINIKUBE_VERSION v0.31.0
RUN curl -Lo minikube https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/download/${MINIKUBE_VERSION}/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/
RUN mkdir -p root/.kube
RUN touch root/.kube/config
```

But i cant seem to get minikube to start, seems as though im missing dependecnies or maybe running minikube inside another docker is not the best solution.

any ideas?

Comment: This will not work. Minikube is virtual machine, that runs docker and kubernetes inside.

Minikube uses Docker Machine to manage the Kubernetes VM so it benefits from the driver plugin architecture that Docker Machine uses to provide a consistent way to manage various VM providers. Minikube embeds VirtualBox and VMware Fusion drivers so there are no additional steps to use them.

Answer (score 2):

I was interested in this question myself, as I wanted to pass online Kubernetes course without making any environment changes. All I have is docker installed.

First of all get familiar with [docker-in-docker concept](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/), because minikube will use docker as well, and I have used this trick.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM    ubuntu:22.04

# installing docker
RUN     apt-get -y update
RUN     apt-get -y install \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        gnupg \
        lsb-release

RUN     mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
RUN     curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

RUN     echo \
        "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
        $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

RUN     apt-get -y update
RUN     apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin

# installing kubectl
#RUN     apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl
RUN     curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
RUN     echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

RUN     apt-get update
RUN     apt-get install -y kubectl


# installing other dependencies
RUN     apt-get install conntrack

# installing minikube
RUN     curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 \
        && chmod +x minikube

RUN     mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/
RUN     install minikube /usr/local/bin/

CMD     tail -F /dev/null
```

**tail** will keep it running after start

Now build the image

```
docker build -t minikube .
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  minikube:
    image: minikube:latest
    container_name: test-kuber
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

**restart** is needed because minikube will restart at some point

**network_mode** allows to access host localhost, other way minikube will not be able to connect to containers it created

**volumes** is docker-in-docker trick

Now run to start:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Login to container:

```
docker exec -it test-kuber bash
```

And now you can start minikube:

```
minikube start --driver=docker --force
```

**force** is needed to use minikube from root (that's ok for me, but you may need some extra work to avoid it)

When you are done, run from within the container:

```
minikube delete
```

Exit the container and run:

```
docker-compose down
```

Comment: This is an awesome start.  My problem right now is that I am running on a MacOS which does not support network_mode=host.  So starting minikube hangs on launching the docker container and never launches.  Trying to telnet to port localhost 8080 fails.  I tried a standard bridge network, but that fails as well.  Any ideas how I can attempt to get around this problem?  My error is: `libmachine: Error dialing TCP: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:61531`

Comment: Unfortunately, I will not be helpful here, from what I have read this is entirely MacOS docker limitation. People start virtual machine with linux to avoid it instead of running docker natively.

Answer (score 1):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

Note: Minikube also supports a --vm-driver=none option that runs the Kubernetes components on the host and not in a VM. Using this driver requires Docker and a linux environment, but not a hypervisor.

Comment: that is true. But getting it setup is where im hvaing problems. Im not sure what dependencies would be require.